# Add custom class to images in wordpress uploader

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image-uploading, masonry

I have a site that has a script pulling images uploaded to a post and displaying it on their respective posts with the masonry script.

The issue is that I would like to have different widths on some "key images". The only thing that I thought of that could work is if there's a way to add a class to images being uploaded (before inserted).
For example under URL, Title, Caption etc.
Those classes could be radioboxes with small, medium or large.

Right now the only way to style images are after they're actually inserted in the post and I don't want to do that since they are never inserted and I don't want to mess up the text.

Does anyone have an idea?

Here's a link to a post for clarification.
http://www.lokalxxxarkitekter.com/web/projekt/broar-infrastruktur/kaptensbron/

Regards, Marcus

Comment: Normally we set class for the image where we echo the image in php, like e.g. echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ); but it might not work in its standard way as you want different classes for different images, right? hmmm

Comment: Exactly, I want different classes so that will unfortunately not work. The ideal case would be to be able to select that in the uploader and assign a class there.